# Using pycurl to get next page google results

Tags: html-helper, pycurl

I have written code to search something on google using pycurl. I would like to be able to use pycurl to do this but all help is greatly appreciated. I am looking for the ability to search a term and then "click the next page button" or "click the indexed numbers at the bottom" using pycurl so I can get more then just the first 10 web results.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple ways to do this.

if your base url is http://www.google.co.uk/search?hl=en&q=YOUR_QUERY_STRING

you can add &num=100 to the end of your url to get first 100 results.

or if you can add &start=N, where N is a multiple of 10, and resend the webrequest to get the next page

or you just use [XPATH](http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/) to parse the webpage and get the url of the next page on the search results.

Comment: Your welcome, can you click on the **tick** to accept this answer.